# Heroku NodeJS app using OpenCV

Tags: node.js, opencv, heroku

I have tried so many buildpacks and googled so many SO articles, but I just cannot deploy my NodeJS app. All buildpacks are out-of-date for 2+ years and none of them work.

So far I tried the following buildpacks:

```
https://github.com/zachlatta/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-with-opencv
https://github.com/janosujvari/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-opencv
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/hdachev/heroku-buildpack-opencv
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/computationaltextiles/buildpack-opencv
https://bitbucket.org/labgoo/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-with-opencv/
```

*and maybe some more...*

**I wonder are there any other ways to simply install OpenCV at Heroku when deploying my NodeJS app?**

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the [exact same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350884/how-do-i-deploy-my-node-js-app-with-a-opencv4nodejs-dependency-to-heroku) -- here's what worked for me:

If your stack is `heroku-16`, these are the Heroku buildpacks you want to add (in this particular order!):

- https://github.com/Starkast/heroku-buildpack-cmake.git
- https://github.com/onboardiq/heroku16-buildpack-opencv3.git
- heroku/nodejs

[image: Heroku buildpacks]

Answer (score 0):

So, it is very well known that once you give up and post a question to SO, the solution eventually comes up!

```
# NodeJS buildpack

$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs

# OpenCV builbpack

$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/automata/heroku-buildpack-opencv.git

# Downgrade to Cedar 14
# since on Cedar 16 it won't work without extra configurations

$ heroku stack:set cedar-14

# Push to Heroku

$ git push heroku

# After deploying your app may scale down to 0 dynos
# ... so increase dynos amount to the desired number

$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Perfect for a hobby project!

Note: if you have multiple apps, simply add `--app YOUR-APP-NAME` to the end of each command.