# How do I deploy my Node.js app with a opencv4nodejs dependency to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, opencv, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Express Node.Js app to Heroku, but am running into issues with OpenCV in the build phase. I am using [opencv4nodejs](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/issues/169).

I have the same issue with this thread at [Heroku NodeJS app using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875940/heroku-nodejs-app-using-opencv), and after also trying several different types of OpenCV Heroku buildpacks, and going through that answer's instructions, I still can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "open-cv-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.5.0",
    "npm": "4.6.1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.272.1",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "compromise": "^11.11.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "google-spreadsheet": "^2.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "opencv4nodejs": "^4.6.1",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "rss-feed-emitter": "^2.0.0",
    "sharp": "^0.20.5",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "underscore.string": "^3.3.4",
    "winston": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Here are the logs from trying to `git push` to Heroku:

```
My-Macbook:open-cv-project guy$ git push staging
Counting objects: 37, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (36/36), done.
Writing objects: 100% (37/37), 47.67 MiB | 643.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 37 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> opencv app detected
remote: -----> Fetching and caching OpenCV (a4c8444d7bae2a219b4ea9cb68919637)
remote: -----> Vendoring OpenCV shared objects into slug
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  9.5.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   4.6.1
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 9.5.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 9.5.0...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 4.6.1 (replacing 5.6.0)...
remote:        npm 4.6.1 installed
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new-signature)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        
remote:        > opencv-build@0.0.14 install /tmp/build_d2fff4256863b9d50ec7ab06c3b8e915/node_modules/opencv-build
remote:        > node ./install.js
remote:        
remote:        info install if you want to use an own OpenCV installation set OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD
remote:        info install library dir does not exist: /tmp/build_d2fff4256863b9d50ec7ab06c3b8e915/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/build/lib
remote:        info install running install script...
remote:        ERR! Error: Command failed: cmake --version
remote:        /bin/sh: 1: cmake: not found
remote:        
remote:        hidden-rides-scraper@1.0.0 /tmp/build_d2fff4256863b9d50ec7ab06c3b8e915
remote:        ├─┬ async@2.6.1
remote:        │ └── lodash@4.17.10
remote:        ├─┬ aws-sdk@2.275.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ buffer@4.9.1
remote:        │ │ ├── base64-js@1.3.0
remote:        │ │ ├── ieee754@1.1.8  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── isarray@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── events@1.1.1
remote:        │ ├── ieee754@1.1.8
remote:        │ ├── jmespath@0.15.0
remote:        │ ├── querystring@0.2.0
remote:        │ ├── sax@1.2.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ url@0.10.3
remote:        │ │ ├── punycode@1.3.2
remote:        │ │ └── querystring@0.2.0  deduped
remote:        │ ├── uuid@3.1.0
remote:        │ └─┬ xml2js@0.4.19
remote:        │   ├── sax@1.2.1  deduped
remote:        │   └── xmlbuilder@9.0.7
remote:        ├─┬ cheerio@1.0.0-rc.2
remote:        │ ├─┬ css-select@1.2.0
remote:        │ │ ├── boolbase@1.0.0
remote:        │ │ ├── css-what@2.1.0
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ domutils@1.5.1
remote:        │ │ │ ├── dom-serializer@0.1.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ └── domelementtype@1.3.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ └─┬ nth-check@1.0.1
remote:        │ │   └── boolbase@1.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ ├─┬ dom-serializer@0.1.0
remote:        │ │ ├── domelementtype@1.1.3
remote:        │ │ └── entities@1.1.1  deduped
remote:        │ ├── entities@1.1.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ htmlparser2@3.9.2
remote:        │ │ ├── domelementtype@1.3.0
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ domhandler@2.4.2
remote:        │ │ │ └── domelementtype@1.3.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── domutils@1.5.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── entities@1.1.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3
remote:        │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.6
remote:        │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
remote:        │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.3  deduped
remote:        │ │   ├── isarray@1.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ │   ├── process-nextick-args@2.0.0
remote:        │ │   ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │   ├─┬ string_decoder@1.1.1
remote:        │ │   │ └── safe-buffer@5.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │   └── util-deprecate@1.0.2  deduped
remote:        │ ├── lodash@4.17.10  deduped
remote:        │ └─┬ parse5@3.0.3
remote:        │   └── @types/node@10.5.2
remote:        ├─┬ compromise@11.11.0
remote:        │ └── efrt-unpack@2.0.3
remote:        ├─┬ express@4.16.3
remote:        │ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.5
remote:        │ │ ├── mime-types@2.1.18  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── negotiator@0.6.1
remote:        │ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ body-parser@1.18.2
remote:        │ │ ├── bytes@3.0.0
remote:        │ │ ├── content-type@1.0.4  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── debug@2.6.9  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── depd@1.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.6.3
remote:        │ │ │ ├── depd@1.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├── setprototypeof@1.1.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ └── statuses@1.4.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.19
remote:        │ │ ├── on-finished@2.3.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── qs@6.5.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ raw-body@2.3.2
remote:        │ │ │ ├── bytes@3.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.6.2
remote:        │ │ │ │ ├── depd@1.1.1
remote:        │ │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ │ ├── setprototypeof@1.0.3
remote:        │ │ │ │ └── statuses@1.4.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.19  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── type-is@1.6.16  deduped
remote:        │ ├── content-disposition@0.5.2
remote:        │ ├── content-type@1.0.4
remote:        │ ├── cookie@0.3.1
remote:        │ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
remote:        │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.9
remote:        │ │ └── ms@2.0.0
remote:        │ ├── depd@1.1.2
remote:        │ ├── encodeurl@1.0.2
remote:        │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3
remote:        │ ├── etag@1.8.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ finalhandler@1.1.1
remote:        │ │ ├── debug@2.6.9  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── encodeurl@1.0.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── on-finished@2.3.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── parseurl@1.3.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── statuses@1.4.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── fresh@0.5.2
remote:        │ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1
remote:        │ ├── methods@1.1.2
remote:        │ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0
remote:        │ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1
remote:        │ ├── parseurl@1.3.2
remote:        │ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
remote:        │ ├─┬ proxy-addr@2.0.3
remote:        │ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.2
remote:        │ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.6.0
remote:        │ ├── qs@6.5.1
remote:        │ ├── range-parser@1.2.0
remote:        │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ send@0.16.2
remote:        │ │ ├── debug@2.6.9  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── depd@1.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4
remote:        │ │ ├── encodeurl@1.0.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── etag@1.8.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── fresh@0.5.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── http-errors@1.6.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── mime@1.4.1
remote:        │ │ ├── ms@2.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── on-finished@2.3.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── range-parser@1.2.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── statuses@1.4.0  deduped
remote:        │ ├─┬ serve-static@1.13.2
remote:        │ │ ├── encodeurl@1.0.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── parseurl@1.3.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── send@0.16.2  deduped
remote:        │ ├── setprototypeof@1.1.0
remote:        │ ├── statuses@1.4.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ type-is@1.6.16
remote:        │ │ ├── media-typer@0.3.0
remote:        │ │ └── mime-types@2.1.18  deduped
remote:        │ ├── utils-merge@1.0.1
remote:        │ └── vary@1.1.2
remote:        ├─┬ google-spreadsheet@2.0.5
remote:        │ ├── async@1.5.2
remote:        │ ├─┬ google-auth-library@0.10.0
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ gtoken@1.2.3
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ google-p12-pem@0.1.2
remote:        │ │ │ │ └── node-forge@0.7.5
remote:        │ │ │ ├── jws@3.1.5  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├── mime@1.4.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ └── request@2.87.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ jws@3.1.5
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ jwa@1.1.6
remote:        │ │ │ │ ├── buffer-equal-constant-time@1.0.1
remote:        │ │ │ │ ├─┬ ecdsa-sig-formatter@1.0.10
remote:        │ │ │ │ │ └── safe-buffer@5.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ │ └── safe-buffer@5.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ └── safe-buffer@5.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── lodash.noop@3.0.1
remote:        │ │ └── request@2.87.0  deduped
remote:        │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
remote:        │ ├── request@2.87.0  deduped
remote:        │ └── xml2js@0.4.19  deduped
remote:        ├── moment@2.22.2
remote:        ├── q@1.5.1
remote:        ├─┬ request@2.87.0
remote:        │ ├── aws-sign2@0.7.0
remote:        │ ├── aws4@1.7.0
remote:        │ ├── caseless@0.12.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.6
remote:        │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── extend@3.0.1
remote:        │ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ form-data@2.3.2
remote:        │ │ ├── asynckit@0.4.0
remote:        │ │ ├── combined-stream@1.0.6  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── mime-types@2.1.18  deduped
remote:        │ ├─┬ har-validator@5.0.3
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ ajv@5.5.2
remote:        │ │ │ ├── co@4.6.0
remote:        │ │ │ ├── fast-deep-equal@1.1.0
remote:        │ │ │ ├── fast-json-stable-stringify@2.0.0
remote:        │ │ │ └── json-schema-traverse@0.3.1
remote:        │ │ └── har-schema@2.0.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ http-signature@1.2.0
remote:        │ │ ├── assert-plus@1.0.0
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.4.1
remote:        │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@1.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.3.0
remote:        │ │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.3
remote:        │ │ │ └─┬ verror@1.10.0
remote:        │ │ │   ├── assert-plus@1.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ │   └── extsprintf@1.3.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ └─┬ sshpk@1.14.2
remote:        │ │   ├── asn1@0.2.3
remote:        │ │   ├── assert-plus@1.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ │   ├─┬ bcrypt-pbkdf@1.0.2
remote:        │ │   │ └── tweetnacl@0.14.5  deduped
remote:        │ │   ├─┬ dashdash@1.14.1
remote:        │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ │   ├─┬ ecc-jsbn@0.1.1
remote:        │ │   │ └── jsbn@0.1.1  deduped
remote:        │ │   ├─┬ getpass@0.1.7
remote:        │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ │   ├── jsbn@0.1.1
remote:        │ │   ├── safer-buffer@2.1.2
remote:        │ │   └── tweetnacl@0.14.5
remote:        │ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── isstream@0.1.2
remote:        │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.18
remote:        │ │ └── mime-db@1.33.0
remote:        │ ├── oauth-sign@0.8.2
remote:        │ ├── performance-now@2.1.0
remote:        │ ├── qs@6.5.1  deduped
remote:        │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2
remote:        │ ├─┬ tough-cookie@2.3.4
remote:        │ │ └── punycode@1.4.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ tunnel-agent@0.6.0
remote:        │ │ └── safe-buffer@5.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ └── uuid@3.1.0  deduped
remote:        ├─┬ request-promise@4.2.2
remote:        │ ├── bluebird@3.5.1
remote:        │ ├─┬ request-promise-core@1.1.1
remote:        │ │ └── lodash@4.17.10  deduped
remote:        │ ├── stealthy-require@1.1.1
remote:        │ └── tough-cookie@2.3.4  deduped
remote:        ├─┬ rss-feed-emitter@2.0.0
remote:        │ ├── bluebird@3.0.5
remote:        │ ├─┬ feedparser@1.1.4
remote:        │ │ ├── addressparser@0.1.3
remote:        │ │ ├── array-indexofobject@0.0.1
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ readable-stream@1.0.34
remote:        │ │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
remote:        │ │ │ └── string_decoder@0.10.31
remote:        │ │ └── sax@0.6.1
remote:        │ ├── lodash@4.17.5
remote:        │ ├─┬ request@2.83.0
remote:        │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.7.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── aws4@1.7.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── caseless@0.12.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── combined-stream@1.0.6  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── extend@3.0.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── form-data@2.3.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── har-validator@5.0.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ hawk@6.0.2
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ boom@4.3.1
remote:        │ │ │ │ └── hoek@4.2.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ cryptiles@3.1.2
remote:        │ │ │ │ └─┬ boom@5.2.0
remote:        │ │ │ │   └── hoek@4.2.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├── hoek@4.2.1
remote:        │ │ │ └─┬ sntp@2.1.0
remote:        │ │ │   └── hoek@4.2.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── http-signature@1.2.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── isstream@0.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── mime-types@2.1.18  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.8.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── performance-now@2.1.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── qs@6.5.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── stringstream@0.0.6
remote:        │ │ ├── tough-cookie@2.3.4  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── tunnel-agent@0.6.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── uuid@3.1.0  deduped
remote:        │ └── tiny-emitter@1.0.1
remote:        ├─┬ sharp@0.20.5
remote:        │ ├─┬ color@3.0.0
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ color-convert@1.9.2
remote:        │ │ │ └── color-name@1.1.1
remote:        │ │ └─┬ color-string@1.5.2
remote:        │ │   ├── color-name@1.1.1  deduped
remote:        │ │   └─┬ simple-swizzle@0.2.2
remote:        │ │     └── is-arrayish@0.3.2
remote:        │ ├── detect-libc@1.0.3
remote:        │ ├── fs-copy-file-sync@1.1.1
remote:        │ ├── nan@2.10.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ npmlog@4.1.2
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ are-we-there-yet@1.1.5
remote:        │ │ │ ├── delegates@1.0.0
remote:        │ │ │ └── readable-stream@2.3.6  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── console-control-strings@1.1.0
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ gauge@2.7.4
remote:        │ │ │ ├── aproba@1.2.0
remote:        │ │ │ ├── console-control-strings@1.1.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├── has-unicode@2.0.1
remote:        │ │ │ ├── object-assign@4.1.1
remote:        │ │ │ ├── signal-exit@3.0.2
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ string-width@1.0.2
remote:        │ │ │ │ ├── code-point-at@1.1.0
remote:        │ │ │ │ ├─┬ is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
remote:        │ │ │ │ │ └── number-is-nan@1.0.1
remote:        │ │ │ │ └── strip-ansi@3.0.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.1
remote:        │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.1.1
remote:        │ │ │ └─┬ wide-align@1.1.3
remote:        │ │ │   └── string-width@1.0.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── set-blocking@2.0.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ prebuild-install@4.0.0
remote:        │ │ ├── detect-libc@1.0.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── expand-template@1.1.1
remote:        │ │ ├── github-from-package@0.0.0
remote:        │ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
remote:        │ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ node-abi@2.4.3
remote:        │ │ │ └── semver@5.5.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── noop-logger@0.1.1
remote:        │ │ ├── npmlog@4.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── os-homedir@1.0.2
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ pump@2.0.1
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ end-of-stream@1.4.1
remote:        │ │ │ │ └── once@1.4.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ └── once@1.4.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ rc@1.2.8
remote:        │ │ │ ├── deep-extend@0.6.0
remote:        │ │ │ ├── ini@1.3.5
remote:        │ │ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ └── strip-json-comments@2.0.1
remote:        │ │ ├── simple-get@2.8.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ tar-fs@1.16.3
remote:        │ │ │ ├── chownr@1.0.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.5.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ ├─┬ pump@1.0.3
remote:        │ │ │ │ ├── end-of-stream@1.4.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ │ └── once@1.4.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ └─┬ tar-stream@1.6.1
remote:        │ │ │   ├─┬ bl@1.2.2
remote:        │ │ │   │ ├── readable-stream@2.3.6  deduped
remote:        │ │ │   │ └── safe-buffer@5.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ │   ├─┬ buffer-alloc@1.2.0
remote:        │ │ │   │ ├── buffer-alloc-unsafe@1.1.0
remote:        │ │ │   │ └── buffer-fill@1.0.0
remote:        │ │ │   ├── end-of-stream@1.4.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ │   ├── fs-constants@1.0.0
remote:        │ │ │   ├── readable-stream@2.3.6  deduped
remote:        │ │ │   ├── to-buffer@1.1.1
remote:        │ │ │   └── xtend@4.0.1
remote:        │ │ ├── tunnel-agent@0.6.0  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── which-pm-runs@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├── semver@5.5.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ simple-get@2.8.1
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ decompress-response@3.3.0
remote:        │ │ │ └── mimic-response@1.0.1
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ once@1.4.0
remote:        │ │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
remote:        │ │ └── simple-concat@1.0.0
remote:        │ ├─┬ tar@4.4.4
remote:        │ │ ├── chownr@1.0.1
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ fs-minipass@1.2.5
remote:        │ │ │ └── minipass@2.3.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ minipass@2.3.3
remote:        │ │ │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ │ └── yallist@3.0.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├─┬ minizlib@1.1.0
remote:        │ │ │ └── minipass@2.3.3  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.5.1  deduped
remote:        │ │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.2  deduped
remote:        │ │ └── yallist@3.0.2
remote:        │ └── tunnel-agent@0.6.0  deduped
remote:        ├── underscore@1.9.1
remote:        ├─┬ underscore.string@3.3.4
remote:        │ ├── sprintf-js@1.1.1
remote:        │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
remote:        └─┬ winston@2.4.3
remote:        ├── async@1.0.0
remote:        ├── colors@1.0.3
remote:        ├── cycle@1.0.3
remote:        ├── eyes@0.1.8
remote:        ├── isstream@0.1.2  deduped
remote:        └── stack-trace@0.0.10
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! opencv-build@0.0.14 install: `node ./install.js`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the opencv-build@0.0.14 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.s30Rg/_logs/2018-07-15T17_55_57_804Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

I've also run `heroku run bash` to try to manually try to install via `npm install opencv4nodejs` on the Heroku server, and see this error:

```
~ $ npm install opencv4nodejs

> opencv-build@0.0.14 install /app/node_modules/opencv-build
> node ./install.js

info install OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD is set
info install skipping auto build...

> opencv4nodejs@4.6.1 install /app/node_modules/opencv4nodejs
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/app/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/opencv4nodejs.o
make: g++: Command not found
opencv4nodejs.target.mk:195: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/opencv4nodejs.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/opencv4nodejs/cc/opencv4nodejs.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory '/app/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/build'
```

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of persistence, finally found the solution so answering my own question:

If your stack is `heroku-16`, these are the Heroku buildpacks you want to add (in this particular order!):

- https://github.com/Starkast/heroku-buildpack-cmake.git
- https://github.com/onboardiq/heroku16-buildpack-opencv3.git
- heroku/nodejs

[image: Heroku buildpacks]

Comment: persistence always pays !!